# What is the best way to fill my VBOs?

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, vbo, vertex

I am rendering a couple of meshes with OpenGL stored in Objects of a class called CMesh. A CMesh contains a lot of vertices represented by CVertex Objects and triangles. Every CVertex contains a Vector with its position.
As the vertex positions constantly get changed during rendering, I have to rewrite my VBO data array every time I render a mesh. This slows down the whole program extremely although I don't have that many vertices compared to other big games.
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: why are you constantly changing the vertex positions as opposed to using translations?

Comment: They are animated. Translation, rotation, ... is done by giving an additional matrix to the shader.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1494740/603688

Comment: @Florian: If you're doing transformation via matrices in the shader... why do you have to rewrite your buffer object data?

Comment: @NicolBolas the transformation in the shader is for the whole object, while the rewriting is because of the per-vertex animations

Comment: I am already using VAOs. Would it be a good idea to create a VBO for every keyframe and always assign two of them when rendering?

Comment: @FlorianMärkl: I don't know. Your question never says *what* you're changing, how you're changing it, how often it's happening, or any other information that might be of use in pinning down the issue. Please expand your question to explain to us your actual algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

use a morph target or at least a skinned mesh with several bones. that's much better than manually updating every vertex

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using GL_STATIC_DRAW, you could change it instead to use GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW which should not slow the program down quite the same. Alternatively calculating the new position of the object on the GPU is also a possibility that might be worth looking into.